# Print next line of given string using unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I have the following text file:

**File**: Test.txt

```
Number of Cars:
    10

Number of Bikes:
    20

Number of Cycles:
    10
```

**Note**: Now i want to get number of bikes next line that is `20` from the file.

**My Try**: 1

```
sed -n '/Number of Bikes:/{N;p;}' Test.txt
```

Output:

```
Number of Bikes:
    20
```

**My Try**: 2

```
awk '/Number of Bikes/{_=2}_&&_--' Test.txt
```

Output:

```
Number of Bikes:
    20
```

**Expected Output**:

```
20
```

Comment: If you only need to look for Bikes maybe " grep -A 1 "Bikes:$" file1|tail -1|sed -e 's/ *//' " will suffice?

Comment: @kometen, No. I want to give complete string.

Comment: @kometen That looks like the obvious answer. So add it as an answer instead of just the comment.

Comment: @pmakholm Thank you. Have done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to search for Bikes you can grep the line and include the following line, pipe it to tail and get the last line, and remove any leading blank space.

```
grep -A 1 "^Number of Bikes:$" file1|tail -1|sed -e 's/ *//'
```

Comment: If i want to check for complete string `Number of Bikes:` than?

Comment: @MAK If the search string is `Number of Bikes:`? Or Cars as well as Cycles?

Comment: That will not change in future.

Comment: @MAK Modified my answer so it searches for the complete string. ^ marks the beginning of the line, $ the end.

Comment: Update your answer with that option too, for future use.

Comment: @MAK Is it OK now?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you could do it using awk:

```
awk 'f && f-- { print $1 } /Number of Bikes:/ { f = 1 }' file
```

The flag `f` is set when the heading is matched. The first field of the next line is printed, because this is the only line where `f` is true. `f--` means that `f` will be set back to 0 for all subsequent lines.

Perhaps slightly better in this case is to simply exit after printing one line:

```
awk 'f { print $1; exit } /Number of Bikes:/ { f = 1 }' file
```

Comment: I am not getting anything in output.

Comment: That's strange; I am!

Comment: Hey that's really great one. Works fine